# How to Setup Advanced Search in Multicurrency Shop

Tags: php, magento, search

I have Magento 1.9 shop with 2 languages (English and Russian) and 2 currency - Euro and RUB (Russian rubles). Currency rate setup correct and in product page I see correct price for both currency.

But in advanced search I need select products by Price, dependency by currency.

Now this search work normal only for one of currency - RUB. Then I switch to English site, search result for Price show me products with my wishes price, but in RUB, not in Euro...

For example - products have a cost 6300 RUB, in my currency rate it's equal 100 Euro.

In Russian version of site everything works fine but in English I setup Price to 100 Euro. In results, I see all products with price unlit 100 RUB, instead of 100 Euro.
Another one example in demo site:
I think it's bug of core of Magento ( I made some tests on demo sites and found some bug in all sites. For example I make search for price from 8 to 10 (USD and EURO - dependence in language store) http://tigermin.demo.emvee-solutions.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?___store=nl&name=&descriptio... and http://tigermin.demo.emvee-solutions.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?___store=default&name=&descr... Search result correct only for USD store (EN), in Dutch store (with EURO) we can see wrong products.

Answer (score 0):

I made need result with some change of search template and new JS.
Unfortunately I can't understand how it must be work "out of box"